# Cannot push sample Shiny app to Bluemix, lacking libreadline.so.5?

Tags: r, shiny, ibm-cloud, buildpack

I tried to push sample shiny apprication to Bluemix with tutorial, but could not build.

> Build a Shiny application to analyze #Bluemix sentiment using the Bluemix R custom buildpack
>   http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ba-rtwitter-app/

Terminal messages are following.

```
C:\test1111>cf push test1111 -b https://github.com/aruizga7/cf-buildpack-r
Updating app test1111 in org TestOrg / space dev as mail@address...
OK

Uploading test1111...
Uploading app files from: C:\test1111
Uploading 265.6K, 49 files
Done uploading
OK

Stopping app test1111 in org TestOrg / space dev as mail@address...
OK

Starting app test1111 in org TestOrg / space dev as mail@address...
-----> Downloaded app package (268K)
    Cloning into '/tmp/buildpacks/cf-buildpack-r'...
           Vendoring R 3.1.0
       Downloading and unpacking R binaries
       Directory created, R pulled, unpacked
       Stuff copied
       variables set
       environment copied
       Executing init.r script
WARNING: ignoring environment value of R_HOME
/app/vendor/R/lib64/R/bin/exec/R: error while loading shared libraries: libreadline.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Staging failed: Buildpack compilation step failed

FAILED
BuildpackCompileFailed

TIP: use 'cf logs test1111 --recent' for more information

C:\test1111>
```

It seems 'libreadline.so.5' file is needed.

---

I tested another updated r-buildpack by virtualstaticvoid.
https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r

And the app is still down like this

```
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down...
```

Recent logs are following.

```
2015-11-12T18:16:29.14+0900 [STG/0]      ERR * installing *source* package ‘gridExtra’ ...
2015-11-12T18:16:29.15+0900 [STG/0]      ERR ** package ‘gridExtra’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
2015-11-12T18:16:29.16+0900 [STG/0]      ERR ** R
2015-11-12T18:16:29.17+0900 [STG/0]      ERR ** inst
2015-11-12T18:16:29.18+0900 [STG/0]      ERR ** preparing package for lazy loading
2015-11-12T18:16:29.25+0900 [STG/0]      ERR ** help
2015-11-12T18:16:29.30+0900 [STG/0]      ERR *** installing help indices
2015-11-12T18:16:29.32+0900 [STG/0]      ERR ** building package indices
2015-11-12T18:16:29.34+0900 [STG/0]      ERR ** installing vignettes
2015-11-12T18:16:29.35+0900 [STG/0]      ERR ** testing if installed package can be loaded
2015-11-12T18:16:29.68+0900 [STG/0]      ERR * DONE (gridExtra)
2015-11-12T18:16:29.71+0900 [STG/0]      ERR The downloaded source packages are in
2015-11-12T18:16:29.71+0900 [STG/0]      ERR    ‘/tmp/RtmpGIUi0R/downloaded_packages’
2015-11-12T18:16:29.71+0900 [STG/0]      ERR Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
2015-11-12T18:16:29.75+0900 [STG/0]      ERR Making 'packages.html' ... done
2015-11-12T18:16:29.91+0900 [STG/0]      OUT        R 3.2.2 successfully installed
2015-11-12T18:16:50.90+0900 [STG/40]     OUT -----> Uploading droplet (127M)
2015-11-12T18:17:00.84+0900 [DEA/40]     OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 5ab1ea29-4ace-4200-9663-01071679a8f0
2015-11-12T18:17:10.51+0900 [API/2]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5ab1ea29-4ace-4200-9663-01071679a8f0 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"5ab1ea29-4ace-4200-9663-01071679a8f0", "version"=>"74c
46eea-a028-412f-a936-3dde010c15ab", "instance"=>"601de49f444b4207b6d000ceae6c30e1", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>-1, "exit_description"=>"missing start command", "crash_timestamp"=>1447319830}
2015-11-12T18:18:57.47+0900 [DEA/90]     OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 5ab1ea29-4ace-4200-9663-01071679a8f0
2015-11-12T18:19:07.41+0900 [API/2]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5ab1ea29-4ace-4200-9663-01071679a8f0 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"5ab1ea29-4ace-4200-9663-01071679a8f0", "version"=>"74c
46eea-a028-412f-a936-3dde010c15ab", "instance"=>"29fddced2254497aaf0a3ce684fe6d36", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>-1, "exit_description"=>"missing start command", "crash_timestamp"=>1447319946}
2015-11-12T18:19:57.65+0900 [DEA/6]      OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 5ab1ea29-4ace-4200-9663-01071679a8f0
2015-11-12T18:20:12.45+0900 [API/0]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5ab1ea29-4ace-4200-9663-01071679a8f0 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"5ab1ea29-4ace-4200-9663-01071679a8f0", "version"=>"74c
46eea-a028-412f-a936-3dde010c15ab", "instance"=>"87796b8ceecd40bc8a1aa0bdcdd00a3d", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>-1, "exit_description"=>"missing start command", "crash_timestamp"=>1447320012}
2015-11-12T18:20:57.36+0900 [DEA/117]    OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 5ab1ea29-4ace-4200-9663-01071679a8f0
2015-11-12T18:21:09.21+0900 [API/3]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5ab1ea29-4ace-4200-9663-01071679a8f0 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"5ab1ea29-4ace-4200-9663-01071679a8f0", "version"=>"74c
46eea-a028-412f-a936-3dde010c15ab", "instance"=>"f01c083e7f824f27a28f044fe33717ab", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>-1, "exit_description"=>"missing start command", "crash_timestamp"=>1447320068}
2015-11-12T18:22:41.93+0900 [DEA/48]     OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 5ab1ea29-4ace-4200-9663-01071679a8f0
2015-11-12T18:22:53.96+0900 [API/1]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5ab1ea29-4ace-4200-9663-01071679a8f0 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"5ab1ea29-4ace-4200-9663-01071679a8f0", "version"=>"74c
46eea-a028-412f-a936-3dde010c15ab", "instance"=>"9decdb3d23d4453c8b436ab517ddcd43", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>-1, "exit_description"=>"missing start command", "crash_timestamp"=>1447320173}
2015-11-12T18:25:12.19+0900 [DEA/32]     OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 5ab1ea29-4ace-4200-9663-01071679a8f0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is depending from the cf buildpack used
https://github.com/aruizga7/cf-buildpack-r

Checking its git updates it is pretty outdated, so I would suggest you push the app using a different buildpack, starting from the buildpack your one has been cloned:

https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r

that seems more active than the other.

Otherwise another buildpack you could use is

https://github.com/alexkago/cf-buildpack-r

So, you could try pushing by these ways:

```
cf push test1111 -b https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r
```

or

```
cf push test1111 -b https://github.com/alexkago/cf-buildpack-r
```

Comment: Thanks. According to your suggestions, I tried another buildpack by cirtualstaticvoid and alexkago. But both of apps were down.
`0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down...`

Comment: could you retrieve the logs? 
cf logs test1111 --recent

Comment: Hello, I tried to replicate and as far as I tried with different buildpacks the Ruby runtime seems to have some problems.

Comment: I suggest you to ask for support using Bluemix support channels